# Symbolic ticks on y axis and numeric ticks on x axis - Plot

Tags: plotting, ticks, education, frame

When I insert the option `Automatic` or `All`, why are the ticks on x axis blank?

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {
   {{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}}, {Automatic}},
   {{Automatic}, {Automatic}}}]
```

or

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {
   {{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}}, {Automatic}},
   {{All}, {Automatic}}}]
```

Which is the right code to hold numbers on x axis (without writing them manually)?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: use `FrameTicks -> {{{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}}, Automatic}, {Automatic, 
   Automatic}}` (remove the braces around `Automatic`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the braces around `Automatic`:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}}, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: ok it works! Very useful reply. Can you tell me what is the meaning of the braces which I removed please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi, In `FrameTicks -> {{left, right}, {bottom, top}}` the elements `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top` can only be a list  or one of `Automatic`, `None`, `All`, `True` or `False` ( not `{Automatic}`)

Comment: Your explanation are very clear @kglr!